# Laravel set ID of radio button

Tags: laravel

I am using Larabel 5.5 and i am trying to set the ID of a radio button.  According to the docs I should be able to do...

```
{{ Form::radio('sex', 'male', array('id'=>'male','label'=>'female')) }}
```

But this is not returning an ID

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a third parameter boolean whether it is checked or not and fourth one is the array.

```
{{ Form::radio('sex', 'male', false, array('id'=>'male','label'=>'female')) }}
```